# R Split a column containing a vector into multiple columns

Tags: r, vector

Is it possible to split a column containing vectors with 3 elements into 3 seperate columns inside of a dataframe??

One column containing vectors like `c("aa","bb","cc")` should turn into 3 columns containing singular values like

```
"aa" "bb" "cc"
```

Every tidyr or dyplr operation that claims to do this only works on strings and formats the contents of my colum as the String `"c("aa","bb","cc")"` (?!) before splitting.

Is there any library that can split **vectors** into seperate columns?

Comment: All columns in a data frame are vectors, and `tidyr::spread` works to turn long columns into wide columns for any atomic data type. Are you perhaps referring to a list column wherein each element is a vector? Please add example data to clarify. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8262231

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but if you have a vector `MyVect <- c("aa","bb","cc")`, you wish to convert into columns then you could use `data.frame(t(MyVect))`.

Comment: `cbind(df, do.call(rbind, df$a))` would be an option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  unnest(a) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(key = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(key, a)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups: id [2]
     id `1`   `2`   `3`  
* <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1  1.00 aa    bb    cc   
2  2.00 aa    bb    cc
```

Using data, provided by Florian:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2),
  a = I(list(c("aa", "bb", "cc"), c("aa", "bb", "cc")))
  )
```